# how to get netmask address from IP in MFC(VC++)?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

how to get netmask address from IP in MFC(VC++) ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

don't forget that one PC can have multiple ip addresses so you will have to choose one..
i'm guessing your question is actually: "how can i find the netmask of one of my local ip addresses?"

then:
1) you can do it easily by parsing the output of the system command: "netstat -rn" / "route print"
2) you can do it in the hard way, using the GetIpForwardTable function. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365953(VS.85).aspx#)